# Lack of Fit Sum or Squares Test Package

Tags: r

Does anyone know of a good package in R for calculating the SSPE (pure sum of squares error) and SSLF (lack of fit sum of squares) for a linear regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at this wondering why no one has stepped up to answer what appears to be a very simple question. Perhaps my assumption that a) SSPE is the same as what is usually called total sums of squares (aka TSS) and b) that SSLP is just more commonly referred to as (TSS- model SS) is all wrong and this is a more sophisticated question. Time will tell. If these two assumptions are correct, then the `summary` and `anova` functions in base R are the answers:

```
?summary.lm
?anova
```

This possibly overlaps with a stats.stackexchange question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36064/calculating-r-squared-coefficient-of-determination-with-centered-vs-un-center  although I think the concerns there were slightly different.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually just found it in the package alr3.  It's pureErrorAnova.  Basically it's a test to see the 'goodness' of the fit of the regression model.  It breaks down the SSE into two components, the SSPE and the SSLF.  The SSPE are true errors, and the SSLF are problems with the fit of the model.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looking at the example in that package it sounds like an ordinary decomposition of variance components done in the process of model comparison except you are parceling out the residuals for the replicated X values.